# Reject Non-localhost Attempts to Access Webrick

Tags: ruby, security, webrick

I'm trying to block all non-localhost attempts to access a Webrick process. This is my current code

```
  def do_GET(req, res)
    host_name = "localhost:3344".split(":")[0]
    if host_name != "localhost" && host_name != "127.0.0.1"
      puts "Security alert, accessing through #{host_name}"
      return
    else
      puts "we're fine, #{host_name}"
    end
# etc.
```

Is this easy to break? My thought is that the hostname is hard to spoof to the webserver itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just bind the server to the localhost ip address 127.0.0.1 and then you wont have to worry about non-localhost connections:

```
s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new( :Port => 3344, :BindAddress => "127.0.0.1" )
s.start
```

(the above code is off the top of my head but im sure you get the idea)

Comment: Awesome. I'll figure this out from your example. Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to mention: this works perfectly, and in fact the line is as you say.